# Errors in importing Neo4j Javascript Driver to Angular 2 CLI

Tags: angular, neo4j, angular2-cli

Helloes,
I'm having some **module not found** errors while trying to use Neo4j driver in my Angular 2 CLI app.

I might be missing something trying to import it.

- I installed it with: **ng install neo4j-driver**
- In my service.ts: `import 'neo4j-driver/lib/browser/neo4j-web';`
- Trying to call this example code in the service:

  ```
  getFromDB(): void {
     var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
     var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "pisikopat"));

     // Create a session to run Cypher statements in.
     // Note: Always make sure to close sessions when you are done using them!
     var session = driver.session();

     // Run a Cypher statement, reading the result in a streaming manner as records arrive:
     session
       .run("OPTIONAL MATCH (source)-[r]-(target) WHERE r is not null RETURN (source)")
       .subscribe({
         onNext: function (record) {
           console.log(record._fields);
         },
         onCompleted: function () {
           // Completed!
           session.close();
         },
         onError: function (error) {
           console.log(error);
         }
       });
   }
  ```

When I **ng serve** my application, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR in ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/ch-node.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'E:\emek\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\v1\internal'
 @ ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/ch-node.js 32:11-25 364:2-24
 @ ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/connector.js
 @ ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/driver.js
 @ ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/index.js
 @ ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/app/services/heroes.service.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

ERROR in ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/ch-node.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'E:\emek\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\v1\internal'
 @ ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/ch-node.js 36:11-25
 @ ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/connector.js
 @ ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/driver.js
 @ ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/index.js
 @ ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/app/services/heroes.service.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

ERROR in ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/ch-node.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'readline' in 'E:\emek\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\v1\internal'
 @ ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/ch-node.js 92:2-21
 @ ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/connector.js
 @ ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/driver.js
 @ ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/index.js
 @ ./~/neo4j-driver/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/app/services/heroes.service.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main
```

angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.15
node: 4.5.0
os: win32 x64

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little late, but here it is anyway.

First, you need to change the way you're importing and assigning the driver. 
Change:

```
import 'neo4j-driver/lib/browser/neo4j-web';
```

To:

```
import * as neo4j_driver from 'neo4j-driver/lib/browser/neo4j-web.min.js';
```

Then change the node looking syntax:

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
```

To:

```
const neo4j = neo4j_driver.v1;
```

This will get rid of the errors you have.

Then you might actually get errors for not assigning a port in your uri. To get the correct port (7474 didn't work for me), I started up the DB and went to the Neo4j browser at localhost:7474. You then have to look down the page where it says "You are connected as user neo4j
to the server bolt://localhost:7687" I'm not sure if that's a default or if its assigned, but anyway.

I then used that port in my uri and everything works now inside of Angular (although I cannot get this to work if using a remote connection such as with Graphene and the only documentation I can find doesn't apply to the JS driver).

Here is my complete solution:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as neo4j_driver from 'neo4j-driver/lib/browser/neo4j-web.min.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app works!';

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const neo4j = neo4j_driver.v1;
    const uri = 'bolt://localhost:7687';
    const user = 'neo4j';
    const password = '<your password>';
    const driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password), {maxTransactionRetryTime: 15000});

    // Register a callback to know if driver creation was successful:
    driver.onCompleted = function () {
    // proceed with using the driver, it was successfully instantiated
    };
    // Register a callback to know if driver creation failed.
    // This could happen due to wrong credentials or database unavailability:
    driver.onError = function (error) {
      console.log('Driver instantiation failed', error);
    };

    const session = driver.session();
    const result = session.run('MATCH (a:Person) RETURN a.name ORDER BY a.name');
    const people = [];

    result.subscribe({
      onNext: record => {
        const name = record.get(0);
        people.push(name);
      },
      onCompleted: () => {
        session.close();
        console.log(people);
      },
      onError: error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: here i get - Cannot find the name 'codes'. Please help

Comment: It was a typo - should have been 'people.push'. Have updated answer

Comment: Btw, you should never use this in production / a public facing app

Comment: hi Epiphanatic , can you help me once again. I want to display the output in my HTML. How to do it. Here is my angular2 and nodejs code --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52741184/unable-to-attach-an-res-sendresult-in-my-nodejs-to-send-data-to-angular-app            and         Here is the javascript code given by NodeJS community, i want to translate it in my angular and nodejs app - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52681565/how-to-convert-the-javascript-file-to-angular2-and-nodejs-app